# Restore-SPSite running forever

Tags: powershell, restore

I'm trying to restore SPSite from backup.

But powershell Restore-SPSite command keeps running forever.

What can be the reason for this?

Comment: How large is the backup file you're restoring?

Comment: Anything interesting in logfiles (uls and sql)

Comment: here is my problem - http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/restore-spsite-failure-due-to-insufficient-content-database-space

Answer (score 2):

Can you go through these links (some known issues while restoring backup in sharepoint) if they help you somehow and in case not, can you run ULS log and record the session while running command again and look for errors only.

[How long does it take to backup a Sharepoint site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22530/how-long-does-it-take-to-backup-a-sharepoint-site)

[problem restoring sharepoint from backup](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/34639/problem-restoring-sharepoint-from-backup)

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/sharepoint2010setup/thread/37537117-1fb3-4105-8eaf-1fae8bfea023

Hope it helps :)

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/restore-spsite-failure-due-to-insufficient-content-database-space

Answer (score 0):

It happens that target url is bigger than original url
In my case some files stored in folders => file.url + web.serververRelativeUrl > 260 characteres sharepoint limit, so restore crach

before restoring check your files url.length
http://fdi-sharepoint.e-monsite.com/